# Combine two string in assembly for outputing them

Tags: assembly, x86

i want to use output with a lable and a contex that the contex is built up of two Byte(string) in memory.but output syntax only show one Cintex and i cant do this

```
output resultLbl, string1, string2
```

this is my code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
resultLbl   Byte "The Result", 0
resultString Byte "You must work: "
resultString2   Byte " Day(s)", 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
            mov eax, 1
            mov ebx, 1 
            mov ecx, 0
whileSum:   cmp ecx, 1000000
            jnle endWhile
            add ecx, eax
            add eax, eax
            inc ebx
            jmp whileSum
endWhile:   output resultLbl, resultString
            mov eax, 0
            ret
_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

and i want to show the lable with the contex in this format :
"you must work: "(resultString1) + ebx + " Day(s)"(resultString2)

is there any syntax for this?

this is the OutPut macro in io.h file

```
output      MACRO  outLbl, outStr      ; display label and string

        pushad                     ; save general registers
        cld                        ; clear DF
        lea    eax,outStr          ; string address
        push   eax                 ; string parameter on stack
        lea    eax,outLbl          ; label address
        push   eax                 ; string parameter on stack
        call   _showOutput         ; showOutput(outLbl, outStr)
        add    esp, 8              ; remove parameters
        popad                      ; restore general registers
        ENDM
```

Comment: Can you show the `output` macro?

Comment: Again, what is in `_showOutput`? Would you like a different solution than calling nested macros and sub-routines?